# Create Dynamic class at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, silverlight-4.0, dynamic-class-creation

can any body have idea for create dynamic class at run time.i have one `dictionary<string,object>` which is contains datatable's all columns with it's datatype my plan is to create a dynamic class base on dictionary. means datatable's column name is property of class. after create `list<dynamic class>` and  bind to grid

it's grate help if you have code for it

Comment: Maybe you should ready about `ORMs` like `EntityFramework` or `nHibernate` because it looks like you're trying to do this on you own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

meta-programming on Silverlight is fairly limited, but [`TypeBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is probably what you are looking for. An easier option, though, is to use `ExpandoObject` and `dynamic`, but frankly: you might as well just use the dictionary. I'm not sure I'd bother going to the trouble of meta-programming for this.

If you *do* go that route, you can get a new empty list via:

```
IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(
       typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(newType));
```

Comment: @Chirag I've linked to MSDN; MSDN has a full example (for Silverlight). The code to create types at runtime is... not brief.